# Associating Additional Info in DropDown

Tags: jquery

I have the following function in JQUery 1.10

```
$("#num").blur(function(){
   $(this).format({syntax:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
});
```

I want to read syntax and locale dynamically from a dropdwon instead of hardcoding it. However in the dropdown, I want to show only country names like this:

- United States
- Arab Emirates
- Egypt
- and so on

US is the default selection. On selecting the country, the syntax and locale associated (which is stored somewhere I am not sure how) should be read automatically

United States -> Syntax: "#,###.00" locale:""us"
Arab Emirates -> Syntax: "##,##.000" locale: "ae"
and so on..

How can I make the blur function read these values. How to store these values and associate them with DropDown selected text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the locales that you are interested in an array and then use the value from the option in the dropdown to get the locale that is selected, for example:

```
<select id="locale">
    <option value="0">United States</option>
    <option value="1">Portugal</option>
</select>
```

Then in javascript:

```
var localeInfo = [];
localeInfo.push({syntax:"#,###.00", locale:"us"});
localeInfo.push({syntax:"#.###,00", locale:"pt"});
```

You can then get the selected locale by doing

```
localeInfo[$('#locale').val()]
```

[**Here's a jsFiddle showing it working**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruidfigueiredo/CpDCq/)

(There are some differences between registering events in newer versions of jQuery, if you still have problems because for example "on" does not work in jQuery 1.10 let me know and I'll update the answer)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/data/  should point you in the right direction

(or just store the locale string as the value for each option in the dropdown? - hard to say without seeing your html)